# PrimaryColor not working properly after updating the flutter version to 2.2

Tags: android, flutter

The default primaryColor is used instead of the provided one in some places like bottomNavigationBar, TextFormField, etc.

Here's how I am setting the colour:

```
MaterialApp(
title: appName,
theme: ThemeData(
  primaryColor: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
),
```

Setting theme with the 'color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor' not working as well.

Comment: Are you sure? I think this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an issue like mine in GitHub and a workaround comment, which worked for me.

```
MaterialApp(
title: appName,
theme: ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: someThemeSwatch(Color(0xFFFFFFFF)),
            primaryColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
),
```

and theme swatch:

```
MaterialColor someThemeSwatch(Color color) {
  List strengths = <double>[.05];
  Map<int, Color> swatch = {};
  final int r = color.red, g = color.green, b = color.blue;

  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    strengths.add(0.1 * i);
  }

  strengths.forEach((strength) {
    final double ds = 0.5 - strength;
    swatch[(strength * 1000).round()] = Color.fromRGBO(
      r + ((ds < 0 ? r : (255 - r)) * ds).round(),
      g + ((ds < 0 ? g : (255 - g)) * ds).round(),
      b + ((ds < 0 ? b : (255 - b)) * ds).round(),
      1,
    );
  });

  return MaterialColor(color.value, swatch);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82996#issuecomment-844956601

Hope this will help others to save some time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use ColorScheme instead.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  title: appName,
  theme: ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light().copyWith(
      primary: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    ),
  ),
  // ...
);
```

Reference:
[ThemeData's accent properties have been deprecated](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/theme-data-accent-properties)